# How do I force yum to download from a specific mirror?

Tags: fedora, yum

In a Fedora system, I can access only ftp and not http. When I try to install a package with *yum*, it usually tries to download from http mirrors. How do I force it to download from a ftp mirror(listed here http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/Fedora/17/i386/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, YUM should retry from different mirrors until one works, as mine would keep trying at school since the http ones were all blocked, though this could help: http://fedoranews.org/tchung/yum-mirrorlist/

Comment: One good use of forcing a single repo mirror is that a caching proxy is more effective since it only needs to cache one mirror rather than many.

Comment: Mirrors are _usually_ up to date, but not always...